# Beginning with Structs in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Every time I try to compile the following code I get a boatload of errors.
Does anyone see any obvious things that I overlooked with my C program. Any help would be appreciated.
The header file structures.h is also attached.

This is the structures.cc file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "structures.h"

void getOnePerson(person_t *p) {
char *name;
char *ssn;
int *year;

printf("Enter full name: ");
scanf("%s", &name);
p.name = &name;
printf("\nEnter ssn: ");
scanf("%s", &ssn);
p.ssn = &ssn;
printf("\nEnter year of birth: ");
scanf("%d", year);
p.yearOfBirth = &year;

}

void printOnePerson(person_t t1) {
char *name = t1.name;
char *ssn = t1.ssn;
int year = t1.yearOfBirth;
printf("%s", &name);
printf(":");
printf("%s", &ssn);
printf(":");
printf("%p", &year);
printf("\n");

}

void getPeople(person_t peoples[], int people) {
for (int a = 0; a < people; a++) {
    getOnePerson(peoples[a]);
}
}

void printPeople(person_t peoples[], int people) {
for (int p = 0; p < people; p++) {
    peoples[p];
}
}
```

This is the structures.h file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_SIZE 80
#define SSN_SIZE 13
#define NUM_PEOPLE 10

typedef struct{
char name[NAME_SIZE];
char ssn[SSN_SIZE];
int yearOfBirth;
}person_t;

void getOnePerson(struct person_t *p);
void printOnePerson(struct person_t p);
void getPeople(struct person_t peoples[], int people);
void printPeople(struct person_t peoples[], int people);
```

Comment: Can you show us your error output?

Comment: `char *name; ... scanf("%s", &name);` will fail. No memory for text.  Compiler should have warned about mis-matched type.

Answer (score 1):

Your function declarations in the header file are incorrect.

You make reference to one or more parameters of type `struct person_t`, but there is no such type.  There is a type named `person_t`, so change the function prototypes to use that.

```
void getOnePerson(person_t *p);
void printOnePerson(person_t p);
void getPeople(person_t peoples[], int people);
void printPeople(person_t peoples[], int people);
```

Your get and print functions also have several issues.  In both cases, you're using intermediate variables to read/write values which aren't necessary:

```
void getOnePerson(person_t *p) {

    printf("Enter full name: ");
    scanf("%s", p->name);
    printf("\nEnter ssn: ");
    scanf("%s", p->ssn);
    printf("\nEnter year of birth: ");
    scanf("%d", &p->yearOfBirth);

}

void printOnePerson(person_t t1) {

    printf("%s", t1.name);
    printf(":");
    printf("%s", t1.ssn);
    printf(":");
    printf("%d", t1.yearOfBirth);
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Okay I understand the function prototypes in the header file now. However, the two methods that you edited require an array of person_t structures. How would that be implemented?

Comment: @Jwils222: Why would 'print 1 person' require an array of structures?